# Passing vars to methods, conditional outcome?

Tags: php

Is there a way, that if thing such as $width and $height are not specified, I can run different things in my method?

```
public function putImgResize($img, $width, $height, $ratio, $quality, $hash){ 

     //$width is specified ->resize
     //or
     //$width is not specified -> do nothing
```

Also, can I specify default values, so for $quality, if the user specifies nothing, can I pre set it to 100?

Comment: Yes? `if (!empty($width)) { //resize } else { //don't }`?

Comment: [See the PNP.net Manual for Function Arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Comment: Specify `$quality` as a default argument: `function putImgResize($img, ..., $quality=100){`. And use `empty()` to check if the variable is empty. Code example: http://pastie.org/8907224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can be modified as below to take which ever parameter is passed while calling it by using

`public function putImgResize($img = null, $width = null, $height = null, $ratio = null, $quality = null, $hash = null)`

Checks need to be placed inside the function for those optional parameters

`if ($width)`